# Upgraded VS 2010 Ultimate - Modeling Project - Layer Diagram freezes visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, diagram, uml, layer

I just updated VS 2010 from Professional to Ultimate, specifically to gain access to the Architecture Modeling utilities.

After successfully creating a new Modeling Project, I have been unable to create a usable Layer Diagram. Each time the VS designer shows the diagram, VS freezes, requiring a forced close via Task Manager.

I have done a VS 2010 complete repair/reinstall, but continue to have the same issues.

I do have Resharper and Telerink JustCode installed along with some power tools.

If anyone has had similar experiences, I would love to hear how you managed to solve them.

Comment: What ability to access modeling projects did you have before the upgrade? Are they just read-only, or totally inaccessible?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Telerik is incompatible. Disabling it completely removed the issue. Re-enabled and it returned. It is now disabled and VS 2010 is again working quite well.

Fortunately, I rely more on Resharper, which is quite happy in the presence of the Layer Diagram designer.